# Scheduled task running under user with concurrent sessions

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks

If I make a scheduled task that checks if a particular window is open, and it runs under a user (e.g. user "foo") with multiple sessions (e.g. 3 people are logged on the server as user "foo" at the same time), would that task check for the window in all the sessions?

Comment: Any particular process will only see windows in the session that it is running in.  I'm not sure how the task scheduler responds when the same user is logged into multiple sessions - whether it will run three copies of the task or just one - but I suppose you could try it and see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a bat file that runs cmd.exe and ran it from task scheduler. There were two users logged on under the same username at the time, and running the scheduled task under that username ran only one cmd.exe process according to task manager. It looks like a scheduled task runs under one session but not all sessions.